# What is this unknown NTFS field?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, ntfs-mft

The Microsoft documentation for NTFS describes the structure of an [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/attribute-record-header). It shows it as follows:

```
typedef struct _ATTRIBUTE_RECORD_HEADER {
  ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_CODE TypeCode;
  ULONG               RecordLength;
  UCHAR               FormCode;
  UCHAR               NameLength;
  USHORT              NameOffset;
  USHORT              Flags;
  USHORT              Instance;
  union {
    struct {
      ULONG  ValueLength;
      USHORT ValueOffset;
      UCHAR  Reserved[2];
    } Resident;
    struct {
      VCN      LowestVcn;
      VCN      HighestVcn;
      USHORT   MappingPairsOffset;
      UCHAR    Reserved[6];
      LONGLONG AllocatedLength;
      LONGLONG FileSize;
      LONGLONG ValidDataLength;
      LONGLONG TotalAllocated;
    } Nonresident;
  } Form;
} ATTRIBUTE_RECORD_HEADER, *PATTRIBUTE_RECORD_HEADER;
```

The final member of a nonresident attribute, `TotalAllocated`, does not seem to exist. 3rd party documentation does not mention it, and actual NTFS filesystem do not contain such a member (the ValidDataLength is immediately followed by the the data runs, as specified in `MappingPairsOffset`.

From the documentation itself, it is supposed to record the total number of clusters (as opposed to the total number of bytes).

> TotalAllocated
>
> The total allocated for the file (the sum of the allocated clusters).

Does anyone recognize this?

Comment: AllocatedLength : is not always accurate (can be disregarded if lowestvcn member is non-zero). & "This value is an even multiple", this value is supposed to always be even.

TotalAllocated: is just a raw sum of all the allocated clusters

Comment: @RamiMohammed; you're right. I missed the difference between clusters/bytes. My primary concern is that this field doesn't seem to exist. I will update the question

Answer (score 3):

The field actually *does* exist, but only on compressed files (i.e. bit 1 on the `Flags` field is set); The `MappingPairsOffset` is then `0x48` instead of the usual `0x40` to make room for the extra field.

This is mentioned in a footnote to 3rd party NTFS documentation [here](https://flatcap.github.io/linux-ntfs/ntfs/concepts/attribute_header.html).

Comment: The link's not working. Is this the same thing: https://flatcap.github.io/linux-ntfs/ntfs/concepts/attribute_header.html